# How to apply distortion on an image using OpenCV or any other library?

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration, opencv

I am performing calibration as showed [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html), but with cv.CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL.

I am using around 40 images and my average re-projection error (calculated by cv2.calibrateCamera) is always less than 0.5.

Now, I want to be able to take any other image and apply to it, the distortion that I got from the calibration.

I know I can calculate and re-distort calibration images by using corners I saved during calibration, but I want to apply distortion on a completely different image using only intrinsic and/or extrinsic parameters that I can save and use.

Is it possible?

I tried passing `np.negative(distortion)` to `cv.undistort()` hoping it would undistort with negative values so it will actually distort, but it is not working and giving me totally messed up results.

I tried translating answers on other ([one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127381/opencv-how-to-apply-camera-distortion-to-an-image), [two](https://answers.opencv.org/question/148670/re-distorting-a-set-of-points-after-camera-calibration/), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612337/cant-distort-back-image-in-opencv-c)) threads from c++ to Python, and also creating my own function by studying the theory behind distortion, but it is not working.

Are there any other libraries or theories I can leverage to solve this issue?

Comment: Your link goes to a page that says "Abandoned" Project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenCV doesn't provide distort function for image, but you can implement one by yourself. All you need are:

- Intrinsic params (camera matrix and distortion coefficients) and size of the distorted image.
  Denoted as `cam_mtx`, `dis_cef`, and `image_size`.
- Intrinsic params (camera matrix) and size of the undistorted image.
  Denoted as `cam_mtx_ud` and `image_size_ud`.
- Rectification transform (rotation matrix) between distorted and undistorted images.
  Denoted as `R`.

The rectification transform matrix `R` can be computed by `stereoRectify()`, but in mono-camera system, it's normally identity (you can just use empty `Mat`).

---

Recall the procedure when you undistort an image, it takes two steps:

1. Compute the rectification maps: `initUndistortRectifyMap(cam_mtx, dis_cef, R, cam_mtx_ud, image_size_ud, CV_32FC1, map_x, map_y)`
2. Remap the image to undistort: `remap(image, image_ud, map_x, map_y, INTER_LINEAR);`

The rectification maps (`map_x` and `map_y`) describe pixel-coordinate-map from the undistorted image to the distorted image. With them, every pixel on the undistorted image can find it's location on the distorted image, and then retrieve the pixel value with interpolation. That's how `remap` works.

So, to produce the undistort rectification maps, you need to loop on the pixels of destination (undistorted) image and **distort** the points.

---

Now, applying distortion on an image is just similar to undistorting.

You need to produce the "distort maps" by looping on the pixels of destination (distorted) image and **undistort** the points. Then, use `remap` to apply the distortion.

Here is the code:

```cpp
Mat map_x = Mat(image_size, CV_32FC1);
Mat map_y = Mat(image_size, CV_32FC1);
vector<Point2f> pts_ud, pts_distort;
for (int y = 0; y < image_size.height; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < image_size.width; ++x)
        pts_distort.emplace_back(x, y);
undistortPoints(pts_distort, pts_ud, cam_mtx, dis_cef, R, cam_mtx_ud);
for (int y = 0; y < image_size.height; ++y) {
    float* ptr1 = map_x.ptr<float>(y);
    float* ptr2 = map_y.ptr<float>(y);
    for (int x = 0; x < image_size.width; ++x) {
        const auto& pt = pts_ud[y * image_size.width + x];
        ptr1[x] = pt.x;
        ptr2[x] = pt.y;
    }
}
Mat image_distort;
remap(image_ud, image_distort, map_x, map_y, INTER_LINEAR);
```

I'm not good with python,so I wrote the code in C++. Sorry about that, but I think the code is not hard to read.

Comment: Hey, this is really helpful, I can now really understand what is going, even though I am having some trouble getting it to work.

Comment: @VictorBian Did you happen to test the code? This does not work. It creates gray image.
I don't understand how you generate `pts_distort`. It just creates a grid like 0,1 0,2 0,3 that does not seem to make any sensible value when feed to undistortPoints()

Comment: @Arya S. The book [Learning OpenCV 3](https://books.google.com/books?id=c7UXswEACAAJ&dq=learning+opencv+3&hl=zh-CN&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifxM77vd3zAhVpLTQIHUzeDGcQ6AF6BAgIEAI) may help you learn more about `initUndistortRectifyMap`

Comment: OK, the grid creation actually makes sense, since it just output pixel location as point. But yes, the code still won't work since `pts_ud` is in relative coordinates, you have to bring it to camera coordinate (multiply with K) before feeding it to remap.
so  `ptr1[x] = pt.x * fx + cy; ptr2[x] = pt.y * fy + cy;`. Then it works, tried it in Python and C++ all good.

Comment: @Arya S. The code works, [here](https://github.com/mightbxg/DistortImage) is a demo, dude.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to get the distort image from undistort, maybe you can use undistortPoints function of opencv to get reverse map. Use initUndistortRectifyMap you get map from distort->undistort, and use undistortPoints, you can get map from undistort->distort points by points, then use remap to get the distort image.

[Inverting a real-valued index grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid/78031420#78031420)