# Issue with Radial Distortion in Image Processing - Getting Barrel Distortion Instead of Pincushion Distortion

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm encountering an issue with radial distortion in image processing. I'm trying to apply radial distortion to an image using distortion coefficients k_1 = 1 , k_2 = 0.4 and k_3 = 0.2 . According to the distortion model, I should be getting pincushion distortion as the output. However, when I tried two different methods, I got two different results.

Method 1: Bilinear Interpolation with Array Calculation

In this method, I used pure array calculation to apply radial distortion, the output is pincushion  distortion. Here's the code I used:

```
def apply_distortion_jit(img,W,img_mat, k1, k2, k3):
    H = W
    dis_center_x = W/2
    dis_center_y = H/2

    for x in range(W-2):
        for y in range(H-2):
            x_norm = (x - dis_center_x)/ (W)
            y_norm = (y - dis_center_y)/ (H)
            r = x_norm * x_norm + y_norm * y_norm

            coeff = (k1 + k2 * r + k3 * (r ** 2))
            x_d = coeff * (x - W/2) + W/2
            y_d = coeff * (y - H/2) + H/2
            if x_d >= W-1 or y_d >= H-1 or x_d<0 or y_d <0:
                continue

            x_d_int = math.floor(x_d)
            y_d_int = math.floor(y_d)

            dx = x_d - x_d_int
            dy = y_d - y_d_int

            img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + \
                               (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+1]
            img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+2] + \
                                    (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+2]
            img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + \
                                    (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+1]
            img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+2] + \
                                    (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+2]


    return img_mat
```

[Bilinear Interpolation output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3bwa.jpg)

Method 2: Interpolation with scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates

In this method, I used scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates to apply radial distortion. I expected to get pincushion distortion, but the output showed barrel distortion. Here's the code :

```
def apply_distortion_scipy(img,W, k1, k2, k3):
    H = W
    x, y = np.meshgrid(np.float32(np.arange(W)), np.float32(np.arange(H)))  # meshgrid for interpolation mapping
    dis_center_x = W / 2
    dis_center_y = W / 2

    x_norm = (x - dis_center_x) / (W)
    y_norm = (y - dis_center_y) / (H)
    r = x_norm * x_norm + y_norm * y_norm

    coeff = (k1 + k2 * r + k3 * (r ** 2))
    x_d = coeff * (x - W / 2) + W / 2
    y_d = coeff * (y - H / 2) + H / 2

    # img = np.array(img)
    img_mat = scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates(img, [y_d.ravel(), x_d.ravel()])
    img_mat.resize(img.shape)


    return img_mat
```

[scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqU54.jpg)

I have looked through the API Reference of scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates, but there are no specific implementation codes. Can anyone tell me what could be wrong with my issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `coordinates` argument of `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` applies the **inverse** coordinate map.
The result is the "inverted distortion".

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html+) is not very clear:

> The array of coordinates is used to find, for each point in the output, the corresponding coordinates in the input.

The result is equivalent to the following implementation:

```
def apply_undistort_jit(img, W, img_mat, k1, k2, k3):
    H = W
    dis_center_x = W/2
    dis_center_y = H/2

    for x in range(W-2):
        for y in range(H-2):
            x_norm = (x - dis_center_x)/ (W)
            y_norm = (y - dis_center_y)/ (H)
            r = x_norm * x_norm + y_norm * y_norm

            coeff = (k1 + k2 * r + k3 * (r ** 2))
            x_d = coeff * (x - W/2) + W/2
            y_d = coeff * (y - H/2) + H/2
            if x_d >= W-1 or y_d >= H-1 or x_d<0 or y_d <0:
                continue

            x_d_int = math.floor(x_d)
            y_d_int = math.floor(y_d)

            dx = x_d - x_d_int
            dy = y_d - y_d_int

            #img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+1]
            #img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+2] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+2]
            #img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+1]
            #img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+2] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+2]
            img_mat[y, x] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y_d_int,x_d_int] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y_d_int,x_d_int+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y_d_int+1,x_d_int] + dx*dy*img[y_d_int+1,x_d_int+1]
```

Note that, all the geometrical transformation functions applies the same principe:

- Iterate over the destination coordinates.
- For each destination coordinate, look for the source coordinate.

The input to the geometrical transformation is the "backward map" (destination to source) and not the "forward map" (source to destination).

---

Note:
The `apply_distortion_jit` implementation incorrect.
Filling 4 pixels as implemented, causes visible artifacts:

```
img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+1]
img_mat[y_d_int,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y,x+2] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+1,x+2]
img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+1]
img_mat[y_d_int+1,x_d_int+1] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+1] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y+1,x+2] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y+2,x+1] + dx*dy*img[y+2,x+2]
```

The correct implementation (when having the inverse distortion) is:

```
img_mat[y, x] = (1-dx)*(1-dy)*img[y_d_int,x_d_int] + dx*(1-dy)*img[y_d_int,x_d_int+1] + (1-dx)*dy*img[y_d_int+1,x_d_int] + dx*dy*img[y_d_int+1,x_d_int+1]
```

---

I am going to use OpenCV instead of SciPy, because there are existing solutions using OpenCV.

According to the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66899575/4926757), "OpenCV doesn't provide distort function for image".

The prefered solution is **inverting the maps**:

- Invert the "remap" maps.
- Apply `cv2.remap` (or `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`) using the inverted maps.

The [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41703210/inverting-a-real-valued-index-grid) shows ways for inverting the maps.

---

Code sample for "forward distortion":

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/68706787/4926757
def invert_map(F):
    sh = (F.shape[1], F.shape[0])
    I = np.zeros_like(F)
    I[:,:,1], I[:,:,0] = np.indices(sh)
    P = np.copy(I)
    for i in range(10):
        P += I - cv2.remap(F, P, None, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
    return P

k_1 = 1
k_2 = 0.4
k_3 = 0.2

img = cv2.imread('input.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

dist_coeffs = np.array([k_1, k_2, 0, 0, k_3])  # (k1, k2, p1, p2, k3)
camera_matrix = np.eye(3)
camera_matrix[0, 0] = img.shape[1]
camera_matrix[1, 1] = img.shape[0]
camera_matrix[0, 2] = (img.shape[1]-1)/2
camera_matrix[1, 2] = (img.shape[0]-1)/2
new_camera_matrix = camera_matrix.copy()

# Compute "Undistort" maps:  
mapxy, _ = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, None, new_camera_matrix, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), m1type=cv2.CV_32FC2)

# Invert the maps    
inv_mapxy = invert_map(mapxy)
inv_mapx = inv_mapxy[:, :, 0]
inv_mapy = inv_mapxy[:, :, 1]

# Use the inverted maps
out_img = cv2.remap(img, inv_mapx, inv_mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

cv2.imwrite('out_img.jpg', out_img)
```

---

Sample output (the input is your "flattened image" with the artifacts):

[image]